# How do I find the mean in statistical surveys?

Tags: word-problem

I have this question on my math homework and I would really like to understand how to solve a problem like this.

In a statistics survey, several measurements were taken and the mean of the measurements was 10.2. In a new survey, twice as many measurements were taken and the mean of these measurements was 10.8. What is the average of all the measurements?

What I don't understand is how to solve it, since I know that the mean is all the values added together and then divided on the number of values I use. But I am not told how many values or which values are used in these surveys. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. Note that if you use something like $n$ for the number of initial measurements and do the calculations, you'll find that $n$ cancels out when determining the overall average, so it doesn't affect the final result.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

- Suppose there were $n$ measurements in the first survey
- What was the sum of the measurements in the first survey?
- How many measurements were there in the second survey?
- What was the sum of the measurements in the second survey?
- How many measurements were there altogether?
- What was the sum of the measurements altogether?
- What was the average of the measurements altogether?